# How to pass an array plus variables to a function in PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a function prototype as such:

```
function do_upload( $file, $id, $type )
```

And I'm calling the function like this:

```
$this->do_upload( $files, $id, 'article' );
```

However, only $files is actually being passed through to the function.  I'm sure it's simple but what have I done wrong?

EDIT:

So $file is just an array of file information, similar to $_FILES and it is passed through fine, I do some manipulation of it further in the function.

$id is set before I call the function, if I print_r() before the function call I see an ID I would expect and $type is just a string.

However, If I print_r() or die() on either $id or $type they are both blank and var_dump() returns the following:

`die( var_dump( $id ) );` -> `string(0) ""`

`die( var_dump( $type );` -> `bool(false)`

Right before the function call: `die( var_dump( $id) );` -> `string(3) "111"`

Any ideas?

SOLUTION:

In case anyone has a similar problem, check the accepted answer below.  Essentially I needed to pass the $files array by reference as it was using up the available stack space.

Thanks

Comment: How do you know it's the only thing being passed?  Sprinkle some `var_dump()` statements in there, narrowing down where the problem is occurring, and figure it out. You can do it better there than we can here.

Comment: You need to show more info. So far we can only guess. My first guess is that the variables are just empty when you call the function. Add some debug lines to your code (`print_r($file), print_r($id)`, etc) and show the output.

Comment: The array $file is sent through fine.

If I print_r( $id ) before the function call, I get what I would expect and the other thing I sent through is a string.

However, in the function $id and $type are both blank... ?!

Comment: Seems like all answers are being downvoted here, so i wont bother. But my guess is that you want to call it with $this->do_upload($this->files,$this->id,'article);

Comment: Well the question is lacking a lot of information that would certainly help answering.

Comment: Guys, I'm not _completely_ stupid! I left off info because I assumed it was a simple error due to my lack of PHP experience, rather than general programming knowledge.  

The variables are _definitely_ set before the function call but for whatever reason, they are not being passed through.

Also, I've added more information to the question which I hope helps.  Any ideas?

Comment: Just in case it's something really quirky, or this helps in the explanation:

I'm using CodeIgniter.

The _function call_ is inside a controller, which extents a custom Controller super class.

The _function_ is in the custom Controller super class.

Comment: You didn't accidentally overload the function in the child class, by any chance? (That did *not* happen to me once xD)

Comment: the call in the CI examples is actually $this->upload->do_upload(); so i'm not sure how this all fits together.

Comment: I'm not actually using the built in upload class, I've written my own (for better or worse).

Also, why vote down the question?  You don't need the surrounding code. I'm telling you $id is set before the call and that $type is just a string I pass in.  Then I tell you they don't appear in the function, as shown by the outputs from var_dump()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your actually running out of stack space (or whatever space php uses internally for call stacks) for the function call. Try passing $files by reference. Equally try passing just a string to $files and see if that brings the other parameters back.

Comment: This turned out to be absolutely the problem and passing $files by reference solved it.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question "How to pass an array plus variables to a function in PHP?"

```
function f($x,$y){}
f(array(),$a);
```

Even if the structure is similar to this it does work as supposed to.

```
class a {
    function do_upload( &$file, $id, $type) {
    }
}
class b extends a {
    public function f() {
        $files = array('a','b');
        $id = "string";
        $this->do_upload($files,$id,'article');
    }
}
```

The only example i can give to reproduce the error in question is this. Perhaps someone can be more accurate?

```
class b extends a {
    function do_upload( &$file, $id, $type) {
        parent::do_upload($file, '', false);
    }
    public function f() {
        $files = array('a','b');
        $id = "string";
        $this->do_upload($files,$id,'article');
    }
}
```

I suggest you take another look at [codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Comment: I'm not actually using the upload class of CodeIngiter, I've written my own and put it in a custom controller which all the classes needing upload functionality extend.

Answer (score 1):

This actually looks correct. The first parameter is passed by reference which is not required as of PHP 5 (all objects and arrays are now passed by reference by default), but that shouldn't break anything. I would recommend removing the `&` anyway.

I think the question needs more context. Please post more of the surrounding code so people can  help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: I've done this, and the array $file is still passing through okay but nothing else is :/

Comment: Please just post your code. If you show us your calling code and your function, you'll probably get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

A few **recommendations*** concerning your code:

(1) use rather camel case notation than underscores for method names: `doUpload`

Reasons:

- readability: distinguish native php functions easily
- lazyness: write less, don't break your fingers for underscores
- perception: Gestalt principles, keep related things closely together

(2) use public/private/protected function instead of just function, restrict as much as possible and open up later, if needed

Reason (from McConnell, Code Complete, 2nd Edition, p251): The difference between the "convenience" philosophy [a lot of global vars] and the "intellectual manageability" philosopy [as local as possible] boils down to a difference in emphasis between writing programs and reading them. Maximizing scope might indeed make programs easy to write, but a program in which any routine can use any variable at any time is harder to understand than a program that uses well-factored routines. In such a program, you can't understand only one routine; you have to understand all the other routines with which that routine shares global data. Such programs are hard to read, hard to debug, and hard to modify.

Consquently, **you should declare each variable to be visible to the smallest segment of code** that needs to see it.

(3) if you want to declare certain method parameters optional, don't set the default value with a wrong type. `$id` will most probably be an integer so don't set it to string with `$id = ''`. Set it for example 0 or null. (code readability, suggestion of wrong circumstances)

* a recommendation is an information of which the provider of the information believes it will help to improve the situation in question

Comment: That´s not true, you can call a function with any variable name as it´s arguments, that´s completely unrelated to the name inside the function itself.

Comment: sure, you're right jeroen, I wasn't thinking much it seems :)

Comment: I daresay you haven't read much best practices in php coding!

Comment: Both Zend Framework as well as Symfony do this and recommend it!

Comment: And who else would you think sets the standards of OO PHP?

Comment: And why should OOP best practices be valid only for certain languages?

Comment: i think the point here is that you're talking about *style* which isn't going to actually change anything here. also, nowhere was objects mentioned - it could be a global function. In any case, the tips might be good pointers, but won't help the OP.

Comment: @nickf, you're wrong. he's calling $this-> so it is a class method. and yes, my answer are general tips. This is a wiki after all!

Comment: Camel-case notation vs underscores is just a matter of style. Zend and whoever else may recommend what they will, but it matters very little unless you happen to use their code. Event built in PHP objects, like mysqli, use underscores. Laying it out like you do; like camel-case *should* be used, without any explanation, is simply wrong.

Comment: He clearly states it as "recommendations" so ther is no "should" do this "should" do that.

Answer (score 0):

How about checking for is_array()? I have seen much code in which they check for the variable, and if it's not an array they do something like:

```
if (!is_array($files)) }
   $f = $files;
   $files = new array();
   $files[] = $d
}

foreach( $files as $f ) {
 // whatever...
}
```